# ASP.Net Core application with Angular 14 showing "This localhost page can’t be found" after publishing on IIS

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio, .net-core

I am developing an ASP.Net Core 3.1 app with Angular 14. It is working fine when I launch it in debug mode from Visual Studio. But when I publish it on my IIS local folder, it doesn't work.

Below is the error page when I launch it through IIS:
[image]

Below is the page when I launch it using debug mode from VS:
[image]

Below is my startup.cs file:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration configRoot
    {
        get;
    }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configRoot = configuration;
        //configuration.GetConnectionString("database_chatapplication");
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ChatApplicationDBContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(configRoot.GetConnectionString("database_chatapplication")));

        //services.AddControllers();
        services.AddControllers(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
        services.AddRazorPages();
        

        services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IRoomRepository, RoomRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IChatRepository, ChatRepository>();

        services.AddMvcCore().AddApiExplorer();

        services.AddSwaggerGen();
    }
    public void Configure(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V2");
        });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });

        app.MapRazorPages();
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

Below is program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration);

startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services); // calling ConfigureServices method

builder.Services.AddCors();

var app = builder.Build();

startup.Configure(app, builder.Environment); // calling Configure method

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
//builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.UseCors(x => x
              .AllowAnyOrigin()
              .AllowAnyMethod()
              .AllowAnyHeader());


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

app.Run();
```

This is web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ChatApplicationWithSQLServer.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 429fe3e4-1017-422e-bbe8-4ebd34060c5b-->
```

This is how my published folder looks like:
[image]

Please help my resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you try on linux?

Comment: Is the ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle installed? That adds the necessary modules that integrate IIS with ASP.NET Core. You can find the installer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Why you are using windows? Netcore runs very well on linux. Nobodies uses windows for deployments. I can help you if you wish!

Comment: @JRichardsz, my current requirement is to use windows

Comment: @ajawad987, hosting bundles are installed. Even my other projects are working. In my other projects, I haven't added startup.cs. That's why I think startup is causing the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, I found that it was some code in startup.cs file that was causing the issue.

Below code was the culprit:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

After removing above lines, I'm able to run my project using IIS published folder.

[image]

Comment: So, the configurations are different in your localhost with visual compared with the iis server?